# Lucene Index Perfomance on SSD Drive

Tags: lucene

We are trying to improve Lucene Index writting by writting on SSD Drive (100 GB OCZ RevoDrive X2). But, we are even getting slow results. Below is some results.

**Index Writing on SSD Drive**

```
D:\apache-solr-3.4.0\dist>java IndexManager
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Total time to write one document=2309 ms

D:\apache-solr-3.4.0\dist>java IndexManager
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Total time to write one document=2059 ms

D:\apache-solr-3.4.0\dist>java IndexManager
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Total time to write one document=2231 ms
```

**Index Writing on Normal Drive**

```
D:\apache-solr-3.4.0\dist>java IndexManager
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Total time to write one document=374 ms

D:\apache-solr-3.4.0\dist>java IndexManager
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Total time to write one document=265 ms

D:\apache-solr-3.4.0\dist>java IndexManager
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Total time to write one document=281 ms
```

Are there any specific configuration settings we need to tweak for it to run faster on a SSD?

Comment: Just using a 1 document indexing as test isn't really fair since the disk cache on your normal drive would probably handle all the IO. However, a 10x difference is quite a lot. Have you verified that your SSD drive gives you the throughput that you should expect (with normal HD testing software)? I'm not sure how much of a bottleneck 1x PCIe would be compared to 4x, but I think that could be a setting in BIOS.

Comment: @Lasse SSDs excel in constant time for random access operation (small constant SEEK time). This is fabulous for index search operations. But, any reason to believe that an SSD should outperform a mechanical drive for mostly sequential write operations like indexing a document? I'm not sure about that...